# how to know input's scrollLeft in firefox

Tags: firefox, input, scroll

in chrome I can get the value of scrollLeft for input.

but in firefox the scrollLeft is 0 forever.

Comment: This is a very very good question! it is just insane Firefox does not show the scrollLeft of an input field..

Comment: please vote for this bug to be fixed!!! it's important:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=293186

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solved using simulate, as follows:

1. copy the input's value to a div;
2. set the input's style to `overflow-x:scroll`;
3. then can obtain the `ele.style.scrollLeft` for the input's `scrollLeft`.

Comment: I think this problem was solved long ago for FF, since i haven't met it right now. But this still a problem for IE (even 11) and seems it doesn't have a solution.

Comment: see a solution for IE9-IE11 at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193755/input-scrollleft-never-changes-in-ie11