# input scrollLeft never changes in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm not sure if I'm going crazy or if this is a bug in IE11.

- Open this demo in IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/zdfubscf/1/

  ```
  var $span = $('span');
  $('input').on('keyup', function () {
      $span.html(
          this.scrollLeft + ', ' +
          this.scrollWidth + ', ' +
          this.selectionEnd
      );
  });
  ```
- Start typing in the input.
- When the text overflows, you'll notice that the `scrollLeft` and `scrollWidth` values never change.

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` is set properly. Is there something I'm missing to get the proper scroll values?

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution to this problem. It took my a while to find your question (and dit while looking for a solution).

In the meantime I can share you a small work around I've found.

Use the following css attributes in a textarea and set the number of rows to 1.

```
<textarea id="demo1" cols="40" rows="1" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vulputate molestie nec dui.</textarea>
```

This will allow you to use a textarea as if it was an input of type text. ScrollLeft does work for IE in a textarea.

If you happen to find an alternative for inputs scrollLeft property in IE>9, please share!
I hope this workaround is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! That is a useful alternative... I'm pretty sure this is an IE11 bug now ;)

Comment: @Mottie, no problem. I will be using this alternative for the meantime. I was looking to solve a bug in mistic100/jquery-highlighttextarea plugin. The bug definition is at https://github.com/mistic100/jquery-highlighttextarea/issues/35

Answer (score 2):

Seems, IE only "TextRange" object (deprecated in Edge) can help with IE 11:

```
var getScrollLeftAndScrollWidth = function (inputElement) {
  var range = inputElement.createTextRange();
  var inputStyle = window.getComputedStyle(inputElement, undefined);
  var paddingLeft = parseFloat(inputStyle.paddingLeft);
  var paddingRight = parseFloat(inputStyle.paddingRight);
  var rangeRect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  var scrollLeft = inputElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + inputElement.clientLeft + paddingLeft - rangeRect.left;
  var scrollWidth = Math.max(inputElement.clientWidth, paddingLeft + (rangeRect.right - rangeRect.left) + paddingRight);
  return {scrollLeft: scrollLeft, scrollWidth: scrollWidth};
};
```